# RStudio does not display Rmarkdown content in seperate R window anymore

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

usually, when knitting a Rmarkdown file to .pdf after the process is complete, Rstudio opens a new
Rstudio window which displays the .pdf output. One can even keep this window open, knit again, and the .pdf will be updated with any made changes to the Rmarkdown file.

Somehow, I don't know which option I changed, this is not the proccess on my system anymore. If I knit now, the .pdf is updated as per usual, but no seperate Rstudio window opens to display it.
I can look at the .pdf by manually opening it with some pdf reader (acrobat in my case). If the document is still open in acrobat, I can not overwrite the .pdf with now changes as I am used to do.

I suppose the the solution is making some tickmark somewhere, but I simply can't find the solution. Thank you.

The test Rmarkdown I used to experiment to solve the problem looks like this:

````
---
title: "test"
author: "The Name"
date: "2023-01-20"
output:
  pdf_document
---
## R Markdown
```{r}
#this is a comment
````

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the answer is just as trivial as one might expect.
The option can be found in the "Sweave" tab in global options.
In "PDF Preview" simply select "RStudio Viewer".